# Consulta MySQL para traer un id y distribuir la cantidad en 3 columnas de cada categoria

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una duda sobre como hace runa consulta en MySQL para poner el contexto tengo 2 tablas: facturas [image: tabla Factrua]

items_facturas[image: tabla intems_factura]

necesito un query que me traiga una nueva vista de facturas con el monto total y su distribución en tres columnas: "carnes", "cereales" y "otros"(sal,bebidas,cafe y frutas)

hice esta consulta:

```
SELECT a.id, b.amont AS carnes,c.amont AS cereales,SUM(d.amont) AS OTHERS,a.amount AS total,a.date 
FROM`invoices` a
INNER JOIN`invoices_items`b
ON a.id=b.auto_transfer
INNER JOIN`invoices_items`c
ON a.id=c.auto_transfer
INNER JOIN`invoices_items`d
ON a.id=d.auto_transfer
WHERE b.id IN (100,104,106) AND c.id IN (101,105) AND d.id IN (102,103,107,108)
GROUP BY id;
```

pero al no haber cereales en la factura 2 este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si le quito el `ON a.id=c.auto_transfer` no me hace la sumatoria de los productos "otros" correctamente y ya he intentado todo y no se me ocurre otra manera de hacerlo.

y para dejar en claro cual es el resultado que quiero hice una tabla aparte para ilustrarlos a ver si me pueden ayudar a llegar a esto:

[image: resultado esperado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: ahora completo la respuesta**

**Primero:** Tu query no debiera correr en MySQL en modo estricto, dado que agrupas por id pero tienes campos que no son agregados y no están en el group by.

Vale decir:

```
 SELECT a.id, 
   b.amont AS carnes, -- no es un agregado ni forma parte del group by
   c.amont AS cereales,--tampoco
   SUM(d.amont) AS OTHERS,
   a.amount AS total, --tampoco
   a.date  --tampoco
 FROM invoices a 
 --     ...etc
 GROUP BY invoices.id
```

> Error: ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

(esto se puede relajar, pero igual lleva a confusiones)

**Segundo**: la idea de tu query es obtener información agregada sobre una sábana de todas las combinaciones, no tiene mucho sentido que tengas que agregar a mano los IDs de los items

```
 WHERE b.id IN (100,104,106) AND c.id IN (101,105) AND d.id IN (102,103,107,108)
```

Sería más eficiente

```
 WHERE b.descripcion='carnes' and c.descripcion='cereales' and d.descripcion not in ('carnes','cereales');
```

Pero eso no sirve, porque
**Tercero**: como ya descubriste,el JOIN no se cumple cuando no hay registros de una cierta clasificación. Esa consulta omite el item 104

| id | id_carnes | carnes | id_cereales | cereales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 50 | 101 | 25 |
| 3 | 106 | 100 | 105 | 10 |
| 3 | 106 | 100 | 105 | 10 |

Podrías hacer LEFT JOIN

```
left JOIN `invoices_items` b ON a.id=b.auto_transfer 
left JOIN `invoices_items` c ON a.id=c.auto_transfer
left JOIN `invoices_items` d ON a.id=d.auto_transfer
WHERE b.descripcion='carnes' and c.descripcion='cereales' and d.descripcion not in ('carnes','cereales');
```

Pero tampoco sirve, porque al poner los items de una tabla b,c o d en el WHERE, no se cumple para los nulos. Tendrías que contemplar ese caso en cada tabla.

Si quisieras usar la lógica que tienes hasta ahora, sugiero que aproveches que en el mismo ON de un join o left join se puede filtrar:

```
SELECT a.id, 
    b.amont AS carnes,
    c.amont AS cereales,
    d.amont AS OTHERS,
    a.amount AS total,
    a.fecha 

FROM`invoices` a
LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` b ON a.id=b.auto_transfer AND b.descripcion='carnes'
LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` c ON a.id=c.auto_transfer AND c.descripcion='cereales'
LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` d ON a.id=d.auto_transfer AND d.descripcion not in ('carnes','cereales');
```

---

| id | total | fecha | carnes | cereales | OTHERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2020-12-24 | 50 | 25 | 25 |
| 2 | 200 | 2020-12-12 | 50 |  | 150 |
| 3 | 300 | 2020-11-11 | 100 | 10 | 100 |
| 3 | 300 | 2020-11-11 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 4 | 100 | 2021-01-11 | 100 |  |  |

Pero esa query no está sumando los registros que integran 'others' sino que los presenta en dos filas. En fin, es un problema contable que te sobren 300 y si la tabla crece no será inmediato encontrar la causa raíz. De paso, el día de mañana puede haber un invoice con dos items 'carnes'. **No se debiera poner ninguno de los `item.amont` sin que sean AGGREGATES**.

---

El problema se puede simplificar mucho agrupando y sumando sobre los campos agregados:

Yo lo haría así

```
  SELECT IFNULL(auto_transfer,invoices.id) AS id,
   SUM(if(descripcion='carnes',items.amont,0)) as carnes, 
   SUM(if(descripcion='cereales',items.amont,0)) as cereales,
   SUM(if(descripcion not In ('cereales','carnes'),items.amont,0)) as OTHERS,
   SUM(IFNULL(items.amont,invoices.amount)) as total
 
  FROM invoices LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` items on items.auto_transfer=invoices.id
  GROUP BY IFNULL(auto_transfer,invoices.id)
```

básicamente obtienes la sábana completa de N invoices x M items. Esa sábana la agrupas por el invoice.id o auto_transfer. Es el único campo no agrupado. Para los demás la regla es:
- El total de un invoice es la suma de todos los *items.amont*
- los subtotales salen de la suma condicional de los items que cumplen con el criterio. Ej
- la columna `carnes` es la suma de `items.amont` cuando la descripción es `carnes` y cero en otro caso.

**Última Iteración**
Si el maestro de transacciones es la tabla de items, ni siquiera necesitarías pasar por invoices

```
SELECT auto_transfer AS id,
   SUM(if(descripcion='carnes',items.amont,0)) as carnes, 
   SUM(if(descripcion='cereales',items.amont,0)) as pan,
   SUM(if(descripcion not In ('cereales','carnes'),items.amont,0)) as otros,
   SUM(items.amont) as total
 
  FROM  `invoices_items` items 
  GROUP BY auto_transfer;
```

Esta consulta tiene la ventaja adicional de considerar 0 y no null no vacíos las invoices que no tienen  items de una categoría, y de paso siempre recorres toda la tabla sin condicionar que existan items de una categoría.

| id | carnes | cereales | OTHERS | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 25 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 | 0 | 150 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 | 10 | 190 | 300 |
| 4 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 100 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aLUktsVbdkYe5bFUwCqoNx/0)

**Caso muy de borde:** habría que ver el caso de borde de items sin auto_transfer, o invoices sin items. En ese caso la solución final sería la unión de ambas queries

```
SELECT IFNULL(auto_transfer,invoices.id) AS id,
   SUM(if(descripcion='carnes',items.amont,0)) as carnes, 
   SUM(if(descripcion='cereales',items.amont,0)) as cereales,
   SUM(if(descripcion not In ('cereales','carnes'),items.amont,0)) as OTHERS,
   SUM(IFNULL(items.amont,invoices.amount)) as total
 
  FROM invoices LEFT JOIN `invoices_items` items on items.auto_transfer=invoices.id
  GROUP BY IFNULL(auto_transfer,invoices.id)
UNION          
SELECT auto_transfer AS id,
   SUM(if(descripcion='carnes',items.amont,0)) as carnes, 
   SUM(if(descripcion='cereales',items.amont,0)) as cereales,
   SUM(if(descripcion not In ('cereales','carnes'),items.amont,0)) as OTHERS,
   SUM(items.amont) as total
 
  FROM   `invoices_items` items 
  GROUP BY auto_transfer          ;
```

| id | carnes | cereales | OTHERS | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 25 | 25 | 100 |
| 2 | 50 | 0 | 150 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 | 10 | 190 | 300 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
|  | 100 | 0 | 0 | 100 |

Comment: Uf, respondí desde el móvil y olvidé redactar en el notebook. Lo haré ahora

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad...